# How to receive notifications from multiple BLE devices at the same time?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

My goal is to to be able to select multiple devices from the scan list, enable notifications for a specific characteristic for all of them, and then simultaneously reflect all of the notifications in the UI (using a `ListView`). Since each device has identical services and characteristics, my strategy thus far has been to loop through all of the devices, create a `BluetoothGatt` for each one, and enable notifications for the characteristic I want using the `UUID`s I found in the device's documentation.

When `onCharacteristicChanged()` is called, I get the new data from the calling characteristic and post a new runnable to the listview that just calls `notifyDataSetChanged()` to update the UI. Does this strategy seem OK? I'm still debugging but I can't get it to work properly so far.

Comment: This seems totally correct. Where exactly does it fail?

Comment: When I test it with 2 sensors, I get onStateConnectionChange() calls with STATE_CONNECTED for both of them, but only one sensor has its live readings show in the UI. On onStateConnectionChange() I have the UI read "Connected" for the device and the second gets stuck on that. When I test it with 3 sensors, I only get onStateConnectionChange() calls with STATE_CONNECTED for 2 of the 3, and the 2 that do have the same problem where only one seems to have notifcations enabled/show in the UI

Comment: So you are meaning that onStateConnectionChange for your second device is never called?

Comment: Yes, that's what it seems like